# How do I get Wildfly to use additional Jackson Datatypes?

Tags: java, jackson, wildfly, java-time

I'm getting this error

```
03:33:14,938 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (default task-1) Failed executing PUT /individual/5a247ce9-0a73-4373-89ce-e4177f911259/activities/432e6e5b-4185-462f-b57e-9ec04bec3d58: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.Instant] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: com.lm.activity.DTOActivity["created"])
```

It's because Wildfly doesn't know how to handle an instant. By reading the error I could simply handle it in that class, but that seems silly. I'm using the following library and am shipping it and all of an updated jackson in my `war` file, but that alone isn't doing it.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I found [this wiki](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQJaxRs)

but my implementation is problematic, the class definition statement has an error

```
package com.lm.infrastructure;

import static com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public class JacksonProducer implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    public JacksonProducer() throws Exception {
        this.json = new ObjectMapper()
                .findAndRegisterModules()
                .configure( FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false );

    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext( Class<?> type ) {
        return json;
    }
    private final ObjectMapper json;
}
```

I put this in my `web.xml` (not to be confused with `jboss-web.xml`)

```
<web-app ...
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>com.lm.infrastructure.JacksonProducer</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

I tried modifying `modules/system/layers/base/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/main/module.xml` which seems to be suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21634020/206466)

```
 <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider">
 <resources>
    <resource-root path="jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.3.2.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="jackson-jaxrs-base-2.3.2.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.3.2.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.3.2.jar"/>
    <!-- Insert resources here -->
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
    <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations"/>
    <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core"/>
    <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind"/>
    <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

My primary goal is to get jsr310 serializing and deserializing. What do I need to do to make this happen? but I suspect that the answer would apply to any additional datatype that doesn't ship with wildfly. (I think [this issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2959) is related )

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Comment: Looks like you should ask Wildfly directly to support JSR-310

Comment: @JodaStephen I highly suspect that's not true... I think it's just a matter of getting the thing loaded and configured and it's not doing that right now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ultimately I was affected by [This Bug in 8.0.0.Final](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2959) it should be fixed in 8.0.1, until then I've downgraded to 8.0.0.CR1.

Here's my Final `pom.xml`, note that I'm using 2.2.3

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3-beta5</version>
    </dependency>
```

my `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
 ...
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>com.lm.infrastructure.JacksonProducer</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

my `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` this is required, and I didn't have it previously

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
        <deployment>
                <exclusions>
                        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
                        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider" />
                </exclusions>
                <dependencies>
                        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" services="import" />
                </dependencies>
        </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

My Producer

```
package com.lm.infrastructure;

import static com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import static com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public class JacksonProducer implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    public JacksonProducer() throws Exception {
        this.json
            = new ObjectMapper()
            .findAndRegisterModules()
            .configure( WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false )
            .configure( FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false );
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext( Class<?> objectType ) {
        return json;
    }

    private final ObjectMapper json;
}
```

and last but not least my arquillian war generation

```
public static WebArchive testWar() {
    File[] libs
            = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile( "pom.xml" )
            .resolve(
                    "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310"
            )
            .withTransitivity()
            .asFile();

    return ShrinkWrap.create( WebArchive.class )
            .setWebXML( new File( "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml" ) )
            .addAsWebInfResource( new File( "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml" ) )
            .addAsWebInfResource( new File( "src/main/resources/logback.xml" ) )
            .addAsWebInfResource( new File( "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml" ) )
            .addAsWebInfResource( EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml" )
            .addPackages( false, Filters.exclude( ".*Test.*" ), getCorePackages() )
            .addAsLibraries( libs );
}
```

Comment: Note that the web.xml and jboss-deployment.xml are not needed for the purpose of getting this to work (you may need them otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

## WildFly 10

For getting the extra datatypes to work under WildFly 10 I also created a file `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`, but with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310" services="import" />
      <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8" services="import" />
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This allowed me to use the classes `Jdk8Module` and `JavaTimeModule`.