# using Jackson annotations in Wildfly

Tags: jackson, wildfly

I'm struggling to get Jackson Annotations to work in my project which is deployed in wildfly.

I already tried [implementing a MessageBodyWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395380/json-serialization-loop-infinite-recursion-in-wildfly) but no success. My project looks like this: I have an ear with an ejb module which holds the annotated Pojos and I have a web module with the REST services. This is my current configuration / dependencies:

ejb-module pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

rest-module pom.xml:

```
no jackson dependencies.
```

ear-project pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

ear-project /META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
           <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" services="import"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

but the jackson annotations are ignored. What am I missing? or did I do too much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RESTEasy and Jackson dependencies should be marked as `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Also if you're only using JAX-RS and Jackson in your WAR, just move `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` to your `WAR/WEB-INF` directory. If you don't want to move it you might need to add a `<sub-deployment/>`.

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <sub-deployment name="rest-module.war">
        <exclusions>
           <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" services="import"/>
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: moving the jboss-deployment-structure.xml to the WAR/WEB-INF didn't work. I got a warn message that this xml must be in the top level deployment, so it's ignored. The second solution with the <sub-deployment> seems to work. At least I'm getting jackson2 errors now : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780208/resteasy-and-jackson-incompatibility-nosuchmethodexception so I guess I'm on the right way now.

Comment: using jackson 2.2.1 now, no errors anymore. But my Jackson Annotations aren't evaluated. Looks like I'll need to rename all get... Methods to give... :-(